# How to integrate API Gateway with internal ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-private.html it is possible to integrate API Gateway with an internal Application Load Balancer using a private VPC link.

However I cannot make it work.

I have a service accessible internally through the ALB. The ALB has no public IP, it balances requests in a AWS Fargate cluster (all within private subnets).

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-40-89:~$ curl http://internal-sasw-alb-355535611.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/health
Assembly=Sasw.SampleService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, Environment=Production, CurrentTime=05/05/2021 08:36:00
```

so all is good internally and I've got my service available for `GET http://alb_url/health`

I want to access the same service, only this time through an API Gateway. So I do the following:

1. I create a VPC link `foo` of HTTP API type associated to the VPC and, specifically, to the 3 private subnets where the EC2 instances (Fargate cluster) are `10.0.40.0/24`, `10.0.50.0/24`, `10.0.60.0/24`
2. I create an API Gateway of type HTTP API `foo`.
3. I add an integration HTTP for method ANY and URL endpoint `http://internal-rubiko-alb-355535611.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` (I have also tried with `http://internal-rubiko-alb-355535611.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/{proxy}` and with `http://internal-rubiko-alb-355535611.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/{proxy+}` without success)
4. I leave the route as suggested Method ANY, resource path `/%7Bproxy%7D` and integration target `ANY http://internal-rubiko-alb-355535611.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/{proxy}`
5. I leave the stage name `$default` and Auto-deploy
6. Create. It gives me the invoke url `https://7ki6gvrngl.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

A GET on `https://7ki6gvrngl.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` gets me a 404.
A GET on `https://7ki6gvrngl.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/health` gets me a 404
A GET on `https://7ki6gvrngl.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/$default/health` gets me a 404

**What am I doing wrong?**
**Is it a routing issue?** My security group accepts any protocol from anywhere. So it does my NACL. My routing table for the public subnets is

```
Destination   Target                Status   Propagated
10.0.0.0/16   local                 active   No 
0.0.0.0/0     igw-08d3973e93dd580cc active   No
```

For the private ones

```
Destination  Target                 Status   Propagated
10.0.0.0/16  local                  active   No 
0.0.0.0/0    nat-040aa996d0fb1a623  active   No
```

Thanks for your help.

---

**UPDATE 1 (2021-05-05)**
I've been setting flow log on the VPC, plenty of traces for all network interfaces involved but I can't find anything meaningful there.
They look like this:

```
2 754027052283 eni-06b3871889a039d54 10.0.50.60 10.0.30.69 47472 80 6 5 399 1620233998 1620233999 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-06b3871889a039d54 10.0.30.69 10.0.50.60 80 47472 6 5 582 1620233998 1620233999 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-06b3871889a039d54 172.245.79.11 10.0.30.69 25610 23 6 1 40 1620233998 1620233999 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-06b3871889a039d54 10.0.30.69 172.245.79.11 23 25610 6 1 40 1620233998 1620233999 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0ec2ff9b148264fc1 - - - - - - - 1620233999 1620234010 - NODATA
2 754027052283 eni-0c2d904cc281e7772 185.153.199.146 10.0.10.108 58226 10089 6 1 40 1620234001 1620234061 REJECT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0c2d904cc281e7772 92.63.197.95 10.0.10.108 55424 8820 6 1 40 1620234001 1620234061 REJECT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0c2d904cc281e7772 147.203.255.20 10.0.10.108 59414 161 17 1 71 1620234001 1620234061 REJECT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0c2d904cc281e7772 107.174.25.146 10.0.10.108 1406 23 6 1 40 1620234001 1620234061 REJECT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0c2d904cc281e7772 45.146.164.93 10.0.10.108 52329 3835 6 1 40 1620234001 1620234061 REJECT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0c2d904cc281e7772 192.241.159.103 10.0.10.108 38868 8088 6 1 40 1620234001 1620234061 REJECT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0c2d904cc281e7772 162.142.125.145 10.0.10.108 43260 49501 6 1 44 1620234001 1620234061 REJECT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0c2d904cc281e7772 104.206.128.38 10.0.10.108 57766 5985 6 1 44 1620234001 1620234061 REJECT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0c2d904cc281e7772 198.98.54.148 10.0.10.108 54300 8443 6 1 44 1620234001 1620234061 REJECT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0c2d904cc281e7772 162.142.125.146 10.0.10.108 33318 15006 6 1 44 1620234001 1620234061 REJECT OK
2 754027052283 eni-02884e94ae95359e6 10.0.60.101 10.0.30.69 37440 80 6 5 399 1620234003 1620234005 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-02884e94ae95359e6 10.0.30.69 10.0.60.101 80 37440 6 5 582 1620234003 1620234005 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.50.218 10.0.40.89 57566 1113 6 66 4862 1620234008 1620234127 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.40.89 10.0.60.197 1113 38912 6 122 7664 1620234008 1620234127 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.40.89 10.0.50.218 1113 57566 6 131 8230 1620234008 1620234127 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.60.197 10.0.40.89 38912 1113 6 62 4544 1620234008 1620234127 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.40.89 10.0.50.218 52812 2113 6 271 70540 1620234008 1620234307 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.40.89 10.0.60.197 2113 34170 6 161 41607 1620234008 1620234307 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.60.197 10.0.40.89 2113 42962 6 158 44927 1620234008 1620234307 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.40.89 10.0.50.218 2113 49902 6 165 43038 1620234008 1620234307 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.50.218 10.0.40.89 2113 52812 6 163 43127 1620234008 1620234307 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.60.197 10.0.40.89 34170 2113 6 263 68432 1620234008 1620234307 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.40.89 10.0.60.197 42962 2113 6 281 73877 1620234008 1620234307 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-05b8087c636058aad 10.0.50.218 10.0.40.89 49902 2113 6 270 70422 1620234008 1620234307 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-06b3871889a039d54 10.0.30.69 10.0.50.60 80 47482 6 5 582 1620234010 1620234011 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-06b3871889a039d54 10.0.50.60 10.0.30.69 47482 80 6 5 399 1620234010 1620234011 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0ae20fdd844224248 - - - - - - - 1620234012 1620234033 - NODATA
2 754027052283 eni-0ae20fdd844224248 - - - - - - - 1620234013 1620234026 - NODATA
2 754027052283 eni-030c3f3c47db36cb1 216.218.206.88 10.0.10.175 39712 30005 6 1 40 1620234014 1620234015 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-030c3f3c47db36cb1 193.107.216.163 10.0.10.175 5065 5060 17 1 451 1620234015 1620234016 ACCEPT OK
2 754027052283 eni-0795bf1958db33aa7 - - - - - - - 1620234015 1620234032 - NODATA
2 754027052283 eni-0ae20fdd844224248 - - - - - - - 1620234016 1620234033 - NODATA
2 754027052283 eni-0ec2ff9b148264fc1 - - - - - - - 1620234017 1620234031 - NODATA
```

I don't even know how to interpret those.

I tried generating the private link, API Gateway and private ALB with cloudformation. No luck either. I keep getting not found when accessing service urls through Api Gateway

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: API Gateway
Parameters:
  prefix:
    Type: String
    Description: The prefix namespace or company name
    Default: sasw
Resources:
  apiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${prefix}-api-gateway
      Description: Api Gateway for http
      ProtocolType: HTTP
  apiRoute:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      RouteKey: ANY /
      Target: !Join
        - /
        - - integrations
          - !Ref apiAlbIntegration
  privateLink:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::VpcLink
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${prefix}-private-link
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${prefix}-web-sg-id
      SubnetIds:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${prefix}-private-a-id
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${prefix}-private-b-id
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${prefix}-private-c-id
  apiAlbIntegration:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      Description: Private ALB integration
      IntegrationType: HTTP_PROXY
      IntegrationMethod: ANY
      ConnectionType: VPC_LINK
      ConnectionId: !Ref privateLink
      IntegrationUri: 
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${prefix}-alb-http-listener-id
      PayloadFormatVersion: 1.0
  apiStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: $default
      AutoDeploy: true
      ApiId: !Ref apiGateway
Outputs:
  apiUrl:
    Description: Invoke URL
    Value: !Sub https://${apiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/
```

Running out of ideas.

---

**UPDATE 2 (2021-05-06)**
I found gold in this article https://medium.com/swlh/aws-api-gateway-private-integration-with-http-api-and-a-vpc-link-602360a1cd84

I can make a sample work if I create a route `/health` with private integration to my private ALB. Once I find a way to have a wildcard route that forwards any url/verb to ALB I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got it working. **It is definitely possible to use API Gateway http integrated with a private (i.e: internal facing) ALB that balances traffic in private subnets**.

The problem I had is that when I created the API in API Gateway through the console, there is an option to add integration, but that integration at that point only allows HTTP or Lambda, and I don't want that, I want a private integration using a VPC link I create in advance.

So here are the steps:

1. Create (if non existing already) a security group that allows HTTP traffic on 80. This group will be associated later on to VPC link
2. Create VPC link associated to the VPC and, explicitly, to the private subnets where the EC2services or fargate cluster are. Make sure you select the security group that allows HTTP traffic
3. Create HTTP API in Api Gateway. On the first step give it a name but DO NOT create an integration just yet. Skip that. Skip the route creation also. Choose a stage name or leave the `$default` (I use `$default` and auto-deploy).
4. Create a route. If you want to accept anything, do so by choosing `ANY` and the path `/{proxy+}`.
5. Finally, on that route, attach an integration. This time you'll see that there is an option to choose a **private resource** where you can explicitly select the private ALB with its http listener AND the VPC link created previously.

That's it. Http requests to Api Gateway will be directed to the private internal facing ALB.

Comment: Is it possible to create the same setup using RestAPIs instead of HTTP APIs?

Comment: @wizard in theory yes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-private-integration.html

Comment: With WEBSOCKET private integrations are not supported. I verified it. Not too sure about rest API though

Comment: This is AWESOME! This whole time I've been setting up api gateway with lambda function proxies and have been annoyed of its latency & limitations. Today I went through bunch of AWS docs and articles, but this right here is so clear and concise! Also want to note I was getting "503 service unavailable", but found I had to add my vpc-link's security group to my private ALB's security to open up access and get it working. Thanks again!

Comment: Has anyone successfully implemented this with REST API? It seems to only allow NLBs and _not_ ALBs for the VPC Link.

Comment: @MattCalhoun I'm trying to figure out the same solution. I came across the following article. It says that we need to use an NLB to forward the API request to the private ALB. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-application-load-balancers/

Comment: @diegosasw - any chance that you know how to 'simulate' {proxy} in private integration?
I mean, for usual HTTP integration I use "/app1/{proxy+}" route and "https://app1.example.com/{proxy}" integration. But private integration has different syntax for URI mapping.

Comment: @VitalyKarasik-Freelancer I use private ALB integration and the following route
`RouteKey: ANY /{proxy+}`
and the following integration
`IntegrationType: HTTP_PROXY`, `IntegrationMethod: ANY`, `ConnectionType: VPC_LINK`, `ConnectionId: !Ref privateLink` in case that's what you need

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! I also had to add my vpc-link's security group to my private ALB's security to get this to work.  That was the final hurdle and should be #6 in your list.

Comment: Since I'm also trying to build this through Cloudformation, I thought I'd post a link to some useful example templates.  https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-apigw-http-api-private--integrations/blob/main/templates/APIGW-HTTP-private-integration-ALB-ecs.yml

Comment: Have you configured it VPC link as a stage variable? I'm having hard time with configuring as a stage variable, imported via open API specification and CI/CD pipeline

Comment: no, @kusan, sorry

Comment: Emphasis on *Private Resource*. I spent a few hours with the wrong VPC Link configuration. Another reminder: if you are going to use the ALB to access an ECS Service, remember to create at least two subnets, in different availability zones.