# AWS: Setting Up VPC Link between HTTP(S) API Gateway and ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services

My goal is to allow only my API Gateway to access my ALB. So, I have taken the following steps, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399975/how-to-integrate-api-gateway-with-internal-alb/67413951#67413951), except using port 443 for HTTPS instead:

1. Created a security group allowing all IPv4 inbound traffic on port 443 and all IPv4 outbound traffic.
2. Created a VPC link in API Gateway with the above security group linked to three subnets in a VPC, each of which have only a local route table (I removed their connection to the Internet gateway).
3. I setup a route on the API Gateway and added a private integration to it with an ALB in the VPC. I made sure to add the secure server name to match that of the certificate.

Whenever I try to access the API Gateway routes, I am getting a 503 error. Based on my research, this usually indicates the VPC link is connected to public subnets, but this error persisted after removing the Internet Gateway from the subnets' route table. I also know the ALB itself usually works with HTTPs and forwards requests to an EC2 instance.